# Configure Spring AOP to be on or off

Tags: spring, spring-aop

Is it possible to configure spring AOP for a aspect around a method to either be turned on or off through a configuration properties file.  The expression for the around is

execution(* com.company.service.update(..))

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring 3.1 or 3.2 you can use spring [profiles](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/) to achieve this.
If you are using spring 4 you can use [profiles](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/) or [conditional](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-conditional) declarations.